# How to click every polygon (given coordinates) drawn using canvas html only one time and then stroke them permanently green?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var ar = {
  "vertices": [
  [{ "x": 15, "y": 5 }, { "x": 28, "y": 2 }, { "x": 37, "y": 49 }, { "x": 24, "y": 51 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 5 }, { "x": 252, "y": 3 }, { "x": 252, "y": 36 }, { "x": 106, "y": 38 }],
  [{ "x": 16, "y": 40 }, { "x": 296, "y": 41 }, { "x": 296, "y": 100 }, { "x": 16, "y": 99 }],
  [{ "x": 26, "y": 123 }, { "x": 255, "y": 124 }, { "x": 255, "y": 239 }, { "x": 26, "y": 238 }],
  [{ "x": 106, "y": 376 }, { "x": 255, "y": 375 }, { "x": 255, "y": 393 }, { "x": 106, "y": 394 }]]
};

function drawpolygon(e) {
  let x, y;

  if (e) {
    const {clientX, clientY, currentTarget} = e;
    const {left, top} = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = clientX - left;
    y = clientY - top;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < ar.vertices.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {

      cx.beginPath();
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][1].x, ar.vertices[i][1].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][2].x, ar.vertices[i][2].y);
      cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][3].x, ar.vertices[i][3].y);

      if (j == 3) {
        cx.lineTo(ar.vertices[i][0].x, ar.vertices[i][0].y);
      }

      cx.closePath();

      // Paint green if the click was in the path, red otherwise
      cx.strokeStyle = cx.isPointInPath(x, y) ? "green" : "red";
      cx.lineWidth = "1.5";
      cx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
// Draw immediately for reference
drawpolygon();
// Draw again whenever we click
canvas.addEventListener("click", drawpolygon);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

I need idea to click every polygon not more than one time. Once the canvas is clicked it should remain stroked green and should not clicked again. Currently, the drawing can be clicked again and again.
How to do it?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Did you mean that the polygon should not be clicked twice by the user?

Comment: I don't see how that matters, but you could use an `if` block to stop unnecessary code from running, or remove the `click` event from the polygon on the first click

Comment: Same polygon not clickable more than one time which was drawn using canvas in html

Comment: So you want the polygon to be clicked more than once?

Comment: @Examath no not more than once.. once it is clicked.it becomes unclickable